# In Java, why would Base64.Encoder ever need to encode to byte[]?

Tags: java, base64

I thought the point of Base64 was to encode bytes into a String. I see in [the Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) that Base64.Encoder has a method to encode bytes into bytes. What is the purpose of this method?

Comment: So that you can write the result directly to an output stream/channel. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking what the method does, based on the javadoc of [`encodeToString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-), it would seem to return the bytes representing the base64 string in ISO_8859_1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use that method to convert a `byte[]` of non-Base64 to Base64, I suppose (in the event that for some reason you needed to deal with Base32 or Base16, for example).